# SELECT * in MemSQL

Tags: singlestore

I am playing with MemSQL and it seems to be really fast. But when I execute `SELECT * FROM [some big table]` it takes usually a long time. I can see a lot of traffic in MemSQL Opt and almost no cpu/memory usage. I have set my sql editor (DataGrip) to fetch only 500 rows but it doesn't help (i know i can use limit command).

My question is what is going on? Are all of partitions going to stream all of results to my client which will fetch only 500 rows after that? Is there any way how to monitor this?

Comment: How is your data sharded?

Answer (score 0):

What's going on is very situation dependent, but you can use `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM [some big table]` and that should tell you what the query is doing in a broad sense that can give you an indication as to what step in query execution is taking a long time

If it's not going to stream all of the results to the client then the client is adding a limit for you. You can use `show plancache` and look for the presence of `SELECT * FROM [some big table] LIMIT 500` to see if your client is adding that automatically. If it is running the query with a limit it should be going much faster, but it would not surprise me if it just truncates the results on your end - which won't improve the speed at all.

If you monitor cpu, memory, disk I/O, and network then you've got basically everything covered. Unless you're using column store you shouldn't be using disk at all, so there's either an error or network bottleneck. The most likely culprit is a rough distributed join, those can be quite slow - especially in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query like that, the agregator needs to fetch all the rows from the leaves, and stream them to the client. The aggregator is fetching rows in advance of the client reading them, so it's going to transfer a lot more than 500 rows over the network, until it fills its buffer. Using LIMIT is the right way to read a limited number of rows.